# How to remove target specified error in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-plus

I am new to iPhone technology, and am integrating google+ in our application by using objective-c client library ([google api for objective c](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/)). I am getting an error like:

> target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Answer (score 1):

The framework out the box (or straight downloaded) is build for Mac OS X if I remember correctly.

Change the build settings to target iOS, for a guide you would probably want them to match the build settings in your iOS app.

If in xcode 4 or greater, you can do this from your project by clicking on the framework build settings, in previous versions I had to open the framework and build it with the new settings, before adding the framework back into my iOS project.

Comment: Thanks for replying me, Please @AnthonyBlake how to change the build setting i am using xcode 3.2.6 please help me.

Comment: Aha, as its an earlier version, open up the google framework as you would any other xcode project. You can access build settings by double clicking the target if I remember correctly (this has changed in since xcode 4.x) set up your targets to be iOS (same as your main project) and re-build the framework.

Comment: i am setting in Build phase tab base SDK is ios